# processingjs gives 404 when loading remote images

Tags: javascript, jquery, processing.js

while try to loadImage(url, "jpg") where url is remote server url. its giving 404 though image exist on server.
Is there any restristion in processing.js for loading images from remote server ?

Comment: Can you post the code with the actual url string

Comment: What comes up to me,do the images come from exactly the *same* domain as the the application? Or a different domain?

Comment: i am trying to load the images from flickr.com from public stream.if it is not allowed, is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you preloaded the image ?

/* @pjs preload="image.jpg"; */

http://js.processing.org/reference/preload